# EmberJS Data - Clean record after pushPayload

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a model which does not use any server backend and only `pushPayload`.

After pushing a record, it stay dirty. How can I make them clean?

Comment: If you don't use a backend, why not use [createRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_createRecord) instead of `pushPayload`?

Comment: CreateRecord also produce dirty records.

Answer (score 1):

by instantiating a model and using the store you are inheriting an adapter and serializer.  If you dont override it ember will use the default one.  So you are in fact using one anyway.  You just need to tell ember what kind of adapter to use.

---

if you dont use a backend you need to use a Local Adapter such as this https://github.com/locks/ember-localstorage-adapter

this will allow you to store the data locally on that machine and still allow you to interact with the `store` correctly.

Comment: I do have a backend, but I don't want to use EmberJS store and adapter for now. I will use them later, that's why I don't want to start to use another adapter.

Comment: @charles i have updated the answer with some info on the adapter

Comment: I know that Ember will always use a adapter and serializer nevertheless I would prefer to override the serializer and adapter by myself to do what I want instead of adding a lot of code and only using a part of it. I don't need localstorage at all.